# findContours() function not returning the appropriate number of contours

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am using `Python 3.8.2` and `openCV 4.3.0`.
I am getting answer as 1 contour when I should be getting 3. I have tried using `RETR_TREE` instead of `RETR_EXTERNAL`. In that case it gives me `8` contours.

```
import cv2 as cv
def getCounters(img):
    contours,hierarchy=cv.findContours(img,cv.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    print("Number of Contours found = " + str(len(contours)))
```

This is the input image:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pr9hp.png]

This is the Canny image of the input:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhIyr.png]

Please, suggest the required changes.

Comment: You are getting the contour of the white background. You need to threshold the image so that the objects are white and background is black. Then get the external contours.

Comment: Sorry , I am a total beginner in this. Can you suggest how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in Python/OpenCV. Your problem is that you are getting the outer contour from the white background due to the black outline at the edges. One way is to use the hierarchy to get the second level contours. Anther, that I use here, is simply to get rid of the black border.

- Read the input
- Remove the black border and make it white
- Convert to gray
- Invert the gray
- Threshold so objects are white on black background
- Get the contours and draw on the input and also on a black background
- Save the results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('shapes.png')
hh, ww = img.shape[:2]

# remove black border and add white border back
img2 = img[2:hh-2, 2:ww-2]
img2 = cv2.copyMakeBorder(img2, 2, 2, 2, 2, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, value=(255,255,255))

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# invert
gray = 255 - gray

# threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get contours and draw on input and on black background
result1 = img.copy()
result2 = np.zeros_like(img)
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    cv2.drawContours(result1, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 1)
    cv2.drawContours(result2, [cntr], 0, (255,255,255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('shapes_modified.png',img2)
cv2.imwrite('shapes_thresh.png',thresh)
cv2.imwrite('shapes_result1.png',result1)
cv2.imwrite('shapes_result2.png',result2)

# show results  
cv2.imshow("img2", img2)
cv2.imshow("thresh", thresh)
cv2.imshow("result1", result1)
cv2.imshow("result2", result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Input with black border made white:

[image]

Threshold image:

[image]

Contours on input:

[image]

Contours on black background:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

@fmw42's answer is correct. Following is an alternative, please read up on what cv2.RETR_CCOMP does with findContours.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

gray = cv2.imread('shapes.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
imgw, imgh = gray.shape

th = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray,255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV,3,1)

_, ctrs, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(np.copy(th), cv2.RETR_CCOMP, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
out_test = np.zeros(th.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

for i in range(len(ctrs)):
    if(hierarchy[0][i][3] != -1): # Discard contours that are holes
        continue
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(ctrs[i])

    if w * h < 0.9 * (imgw * imgh): # Eliminates white square surrounding the whole image
        cv2.drawContours(out_test, [ctrs[i]], -1, 255, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Fast way to do this is: In your code, find contours using RETR_TREE. As you said, this will give a total of 8 contours. Now we have to eliminate all the outer contours, that is the required contours are those at the inner edge of the shapes. As you can notice, these contours of the inner edge will have no child contour. Thus, use this observation.

[Refer this for info about parent-child relation in contours](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_hierarchy/py_contours_hierarchy.html)

One liner code to do this would be -

```
contours = np.asarray([contours[i] for i in range(len(contours)) if hierarchy[0][i][2] == -1])
```